# How do you retrieve a vector from a CopyDataStruct?

Tags: c++, winapi

Send:

```
 vector<string> vs;
 cds.lpData = &vs;
```

**How would i retrieve this in the WM_COPYDATA message**, I can't seem to cast the void pointer in the recieving section to a string vector.

Heres what I've come up with so far:

Sent:

```
 cds.lpData = &vs;
```

Recieving End:

```
 case WM_COPYDATA:
{
    COPYDATASTRUCT *cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT *)lParam;
    if(cds->dwData == CDS_TAG)
    {

   vector<string> * vs;
   vs = (vector<string>*)((cds->lpData));

    }
}
```

**How would one dereference a pointer to a vector?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you indexing the vector?

Comment: My strings have already been added to the vector. My mistake allow me to edit.

Comment: Looks like you need to use `vs[x].c_str();` and use `vs[x].size()` to set the size of the `WM_COPYDATA` data size;

Comment: You are passing a pointer to a `string` but there is no guarantee that `string` is blittable.

Comment: Using vs[x].c_str(); says invalid conversion from const void* to void* any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You deference a pointer to a vector the same way you dereference any other pointer: prefix it with the `*` operator. In your case, `*vs` would be your vector, so `(*vs)[0]` would be the first element.

But you're getting ahead of yourself. The `WM_COPYDATA` message is for sending data between processes, but `vector` and `string` are not types you can copy between processes and expect to work. You can only use POD types since Windows is going to copy the raw memory from one process to the other; it won't call constructors or do deep copies of internal pointers.

You need to serialize your data structure so it's all one contiguous block of memory. Then you can use the message to send it elsewhere. Deserialize on the receiving end by inverting whatever you do to serialize.

Comment: I managed to copy a vector this way. Im not sure if there are any issues this could lead to though:

Comment: There are different issues depending on *where* you sent it. If you sent it to a window within your process, then you didn't need to use the copy-data message in the first place; you could have passed a vector pointer directly in any message's parameters. If you sent it to a window in a different process, then you did it wrong because you didn't actually send any of the strings, and the memory pointers in the vector refer to the originating process's address space, not the target process's.

Answer (score 0):

Send:

```
cds.lpData = &vs;
```

Receive:

```
 vector<string> * vs;
    vs = (vector<string>*)((cds->lpData));
    vs->at(//Whatever element you need to obtain);
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the code in the question, which didn't work?